# C# How to add my program to context menu?

Tags: c#, contextmenu, executable, shortcut

I have a c# executable file (created from a windows form application) and I would like to be able to add this file to the context menu. Furthermore, I should point out that I need to be able to add it to Windows XP, Vista, and 7.

Thank you for any help,

Comment: The "shortcut" you are talking about is called context menu.

Comment: Thank you - I couldn't think of the correct name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not that difficult and it is called context menu.  Check this out [Add a context menu to the Windows Explorer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/appendmenu.aspx)
Basically you will need to add item to the Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey registry.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah add context menu using Registry editor. You could do this manually. Or this method, for example [MSDN LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e7chcf.aspx), but you only need to do it once. so its like a installer executed once. here another simple example [Link](http://www.mytechyard.com/2011/03/add-right-click-context-menu-entry-for-shutdown-from-desktop/)